# executing mysql restore cmd in java runtimeProcess.waitFor() returns 1 always

Tags: java, mysql, command-line, restore

The following code is always returning 1. I do not understand why.

```
String executeCmd[] = {"mysql"," -u" + dbUser," -p" + dbPass," -A"," -D"+dbName ," < " + restorePath};

Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

if (processComplete == 0) {
    System.out.println("Successfully restored from SQL : " + s);
} else {
    System.out.println("Error at restoring");
}
```

Comment: are you running on Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am in linux environment.

Comment: Input redirection ("<") is handled by the shell ("bash") and not by your OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have grilled my head trying to solve this problem for a week and I have finally figured it out.

The problem is, the `<` in above code (stream redirection). You cannot use stream redirection when executing a process in Java (it simply does not work in this case).

So, you have to do it without using stream redirection. One way of doing it is:

```
mysql -u root -p**** --execute "SOURCE \\path\\to\\sql"
```

Try:

```
String executeCmd[] = {"mysql"," -u "+dbUser," -p"+dbPass," -A"," -D"+dbName," --execute"," \"SOURCE "+restorePath+"\""};
```

or simply:

```
String executeCmd = "mysql -u "+dbUser+" -p"+dbPass+" -A -D "+"dbName -e \"SOURCE "+restorePath+"\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect `<` is interpreted by the command shell. Try

```
String executeCmd[] =
       {"bash", "-c", "mysql", "-u", dbUser, "-p", dbPass, "-A","-D", dbName , "< ", restorePath};
```

Comment: I think the parameters should not be concatenated: `"-u" + dbUser` -> `"-u", dbUser`

Comment: @Bee what error do you see when you read the `ErrorStream` of the `runtimeProcess`?

Comment: no errorstream is printed but the processComplete is becoming 1 InputStream error = runtimeProcess.getErrorStream();
            for (int i = 0; i < error.available(); i++) {
            System.out.println("errorrrr\n" + error.read());
            }
@Reimeus